# JUnit assertion failures are hideous. What can be done?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, stack-trace, spock

I run my unit tests from the command line, invoking `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`, and I find the way JUnit vomits assertion failures in my face with 35 lines of stack trace of which only 1 is relevant to me quite annoying.

I’ve been playing around with the [Spock Framework](https://code.google.com/p/spock/) recently, and I find its output beautiful. However, its documentation seems to be lacking and the whole framework seems to be too much magic, so for now I prefer to stick with simpler, more well-known tools.

So my question is if there’s a way to get JUnit display more to the point output without the irrelevant stack frames, at least in the case of assertion errors. Getting the detailed descriptions of assertions and concise exception reports of Spock would be nice, though.

I use the command line, so IDEs are off the table, but I’m willing to trade JUnit for other solutions as long as they are simple, elegant and have good support.

Comment: IDE is ultimate solution of you problem. But if for some reason you can't use it it take several days and you learn haw to find useful information in stack trace very fast.

Comment: I’ve been reading stack traces for a decade, it’s not a problem of finding the useful bits fast, it’s the cognitive overhead of scanning and discarding (and scrolling) irrelevant information, especially when you test drive your code and assertion failures occur every step, not just occasionally. I don’t use IDEs because I don’t like integrated solutions – I follow the Unix philosophy when it comes to development tools.

Comment: Maybe it is not easy to find, but I find [Spock's documentation](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/) quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit has a [runListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) class which lets you get test results.  This is how IDEs and build tools get test results.  You can then format the test results anyway you want.

```
public class MyTestListener extends RunListener {
    public void testFailure(Failure failure) {
         //this just prints the message instead of the whole stack
         //printing to STDOUT but you can print to file or whatever
         System.out.println(failure.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

Then create a JUnitCore in a main method and add the listener:

```
  public class RunMyTests{

   public void main(String... args) {
       JUnitCore core= new JUnitCore();
       core.addListener(new MyTestListener());
       core.run(MyTestSuite.class);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use AssertJ (http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/). The fluent API is pure heaven and the log messages are really more relevant than the JUnit ones. However, I think you will still have the stacktraces so that may not correct all of your problem but still, I think it is worth to use.

Comment: AssertJ in fact filters the stack trace! http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/internal/Failures.html#removeAssertJRelatedElementsFromStackTraceIfNeeded(java.lang.AssertionError)

Comment: I didn't know. Thanks for this, it is great !